# Cannot load audio files using AudioSegment

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-science-model, audio-recognition

I am trying to load an mp3 file using pydub's AudioSegment method with below code.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
from noisereduce import reduce_noise
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

# Open the audio file using a file object
with open("wind__artic__cold-6195.mp3", "rb") as f:
    audio_data = f.read()

# Save the audio data to a temporary WAV file
with open("temp_audio.wav", "wb") as temp_audio_file:
    temp_audio_file.write(audio_data)

# Load the temporary WAV file with AudioSegment
audio = AudioSegment.from_wav("temp_audio.wav")

# Apply noise reduction
audio_samples = np.array(audio.get_array_of_samples())
reduced_audio_data = reduce_noise(y=audio_samples, sr=audio.frame_rate, n_std_thresh=2, prop_decrease=1.0, verbose=False)
reduced_audio = AudioSegment(reduced_audio_data.tobytes(), frame_rate=audio.frame_rate, sample_width=reduced_audio_data.dtype.itemsize, channels=1)

# Smooth the audio
smoothed_audio = reduced_audio.low_pass_filter(3000)  # Adjust the cutoff frequency as needed

# Save the processed audio
smoothed_audio.export("output_audio.wav", format="wav")

# Clean up the temporary WAV file
import os
os.remove("temp_audio.wav")
```

But continuously I am getting error as :

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Do anyone have resolved this kind of issue?